# Sliding selector in android

Tags: android

I have three types of categories , i want to select each type on sliding from left to right, like a sliding selector.Any help would be appreciated [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a seekbar for this requirement.

in your xml file Create a seek bar.

```
 <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

Use the setOnSeekBarChangeListener for listening for the changes in the seek,

```
SeekBar skbarVisibleWithin = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
        skbarVisibleWithin.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                /**
                 * if the progress is less than 25 than we should set
                 * the progress to 0, else if the progress is less than
                 * 75 then we should set the progress as 50 else set the
                 * progress as 100;
                 **/
                int progress = seekBar.getProgress();
                if (progress < 25) {
                    seekBar.setProgress(PROGRESS_STAGE_1);
                }
                else if (progress < 75) {
                    seekBar.setProgress(PROGRESS_STAGE_2);
                }
                else {
                    seekBar.setProgress(PROGRESS_STAGE_3);
                }
            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if (progress == PROGRESS_STAGE_1) {
                    //TODO: 
                }
                else if (progress == PROGRESS_STAGE_2) {
                    //TODO: 
                }
                else if (progress == PROGRESS_STAGE_3) {
                    //TODO: 
                }
            }
        });
```

In the onProgessChanged, manually set the progess.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Hardik4560 code i have customized his code and created a seek selector 
i am sharing this code may be this will help someone anybody knows a better solution please update.....

Xml for seek bar

Code

```
mainSeekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.mainSeekBar);
        mainSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO something fancy here
                int progress = seekBar.getProgress();
                if (progress > 0 && progress < 40) {

                    if (seekBar.getProgress() > 20) {
                        progress = PROGRESS_STAGE_2;
                        seekBar.setProgress(PROGRESS_STAGE_2);
                    } else {
                        progress = PROGRESS_STAGE_1;
                        seekBar.setProgress(PROGRESS_STAGE_1);
                    }

                } else if (progress > 40 && progress < 70) {

                    if (seekBar.getProgress() > 55) {
                        progress = PROGRESS_STAGE_3;
                        seekBar.setProgress(PROGRESS_STAGE_3);
                    } else {
                        progress = PROGRESS_STAGE_2;
                        seekBar.setProgress(PROGRESS_STAGE_2);
                    }

                } else if (progress > 70 && progress < 100) {

                    if (seekBar.getProgress() > 86) {
                        progress = PROGRESS_STAGE_4;
                        seekBar.setProgress(PROGRESS_STAGE_4);
                    } else {
                        progress = PROGRESS_STAGE_3;
                        seekBar.setProgress(PROGRESS_STAGE_3);
                    }
                }
            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO something fancy here
            }

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // progressTextView.setText(String.valueOf(progress) + '%');

                if (progress == PROGRESS_STAGE_1) {
                    // TODO:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "type 1",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (progress == PROGRESS_STAGE_2) {
                    // TODO:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "type 2",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (progress == PROGRESS_STAGE_3) {
                    // TODO:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "type 3",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (progress == PROGRESS_STAGE_4) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "type 4",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

SeekBar custom backgrounds

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

     <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <nine-patch
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:dither="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back_seekbar" />
    </item> 
    <!-- <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <bitmap
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:antialias="true"
            android:filter="false"
            android:dither="false"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:src="@drawable/back_progress"
            android:tileMode="repeat" />
    </item>  -->

</layer-list>
```